# How to accelerate the FLV video in RTMP?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flv, rtmp, acceleration

I've been stucked  with this requirement for a long time.And how can I do that?Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean obtaining something like a 4x video play speed?

Comment: @ Cornel Creanga,yep,that's exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are several options

a)Do the processing on the Flash Player (skip frames) - I think it is inefficient and I do not think that you will have a good user experience - but you can give it a try

b)Write a plugin for your streaming server (in FMS you can do it in C++) which is doing the same thing - skipping frames in order to obtain the desired effect.

c)Encode your video files in several formats: 1x, 2x, 4x etc and switch the stream from the flash player accordingly. I think this is the easiest solution.

Comment: perhaps the #c is feasible though costs.Thanks for the suggestion